# Certain site loads very slowly - usually times out

Tags: firefox, internet, browser

Freelancer.com for me is loading very slowly, and all other sites load fine.

This occurs in all browsers (FF, Chrome, IE) latest versions.

When I access through http://anonymouse.org/ or Hidemyass it loads completely fine.

I use Google DNS and have tried turning this off to no avail. I do not use any proxies.

Any help much appreciated.

Edit:

This is the traceroute if it is of any help:

```
Tracing route to freelancer.com [174.129.12.136]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    10 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.2.1
  2    56 ms    58 ms    56 ms  rb5-lo1.core.global.net.uk [xx.xx.xx.xxx]
  3    66 ms    57 ms    61 ms  rb2-ge0-3v405.core.global.net.uk [xx.xx.xx.xxx]

  4   259 ms    65 ms    74 ms  po2.pte-gw1.plus.net [xx.xx.xx.xxx]
  5   470 ms   264 ms   247 ms  vl22.thn-gw1.plus.net [xx.xx.xx.xxx]
  6    57 ms    57 ms    59 ms  te3-2.ptn-gw01.plus.net [xx.xx.xx.xxx]
  7   129 ms    65 ms    57 ms  t2a1-ge2-0-0.uk-lon1.eu.bt.net [xx.xx.xx.xxx]
  8   216 ms    62 ms    69 ms  t2c2-ge2-0-0.uk-lon1.eu.bt.net [xx.xx.xx.xxx]

  9   306 ms    63 ms    58 ms  t2c1-p4-2.uk-eal.eu.bt.net [xx.xx.xx.xxx]
 10   267 ms   150 ms   141 ms  t2c1-p4-0-0.us-ash.eu.bt.net [xx.xx.xx.xxx]
 11   208 ms   197 ms   221 ms  equinix01-iad2.amazon.com [xx.xx.xx.xxx]
 12   163 ms   141 ms   131 ms  xx.xx.xx.xxx
 13   178 ms   319 ms   170 ms  xx.xx.xx.xxx
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *
```

Comment: Try doing a regular ping from your location. I'm getting timed out as well, but getting through to the site just fine and ping as well. (Traceroute issues is not allways network issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a network problem between you and the site, that's why accessing through a different location works fine.

You probably cannot solve this yourself, but if it persists you can contact your network provider or change provider if the connectivity isn't good enough.

You can do a traceroute to get some idea of where the issue may lie and forward the same info to your network provider.

Edit2*:
I just noticed that it was hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance. They may have done changes to the DNS which takes time to propogate. You might try one of the following:

On windows:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

You might find a temporary fix using alternate DNS-servers, but the problem should clear itself up.

Comment: +1 - I added an additional option but I think you are right on this one.

Comment: Excellent thanks - ipconfig /flushdns worked a dream.

Comment: Great it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

One other option could be an issue in your hosts file.  Check the file at:
`C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc`

It is called `hosts.` and contains redirects specific to your pc.  Make sure there is not a line mentioning that site, or it's IP address.

I think it is likely just an issue with the internet between you and  the site and it should probably fix itself soon.

Comment: Nothing in the hosts file related to freelancer.com or it's IP. Also, the issue has been persisting for some weeks now and hasn't resolved at all.